# Xamarin Forms Tap gesture recognizer Ios doesn't work

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem about some Gesture Recognizer into my `Xamarin` Forms project.
I was working to set three Image into a grid layer to see a viewfinder with `Zxing` Forms library to go into specific page and manage the flash camera device.

After I compiled and build my project, into Android device works perfectly, besided Ios that when I touch an image of them they didn't work not at all. I don't make any mistake to write the code.

Tap recognizer for example are wrote like these:

```
var settingsGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
settingsGestureRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
settingsGestureRecognizer.Tapped += async(s, e) =>
    {
        // handle the tap
        NavigationPage nav = new NavigationPage(new SettingsPage());
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(nav);
    };
```

And also, I add it into a button of a `StackLayout` like these

```
settingsImage = new Image
    {
        Source = ImageSource.FromFile(ConstantStringCollector.iconSettings),
        Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
        WidthRequest = 45,
        HeightRequest = 45,
        MinimumHeightRequest = 45,
        MinimumWidthRequest = 45,
        IsEnabled = true
    };
settingsImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(settingsGestureRecognizer);
```

And then there is my personal layout

```
StackLayout stackLayoutBottom = new StackLayout
{
    IsEnabled = true,
    IsVisible = true,
    IsClippedToBounds = true,
    Padding = new Thickness(20, 20),
    BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
    Opacity = 0.8,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    Children = {
                infoImage,
                flashImage,
                settingsImage
                }

};
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: The code you posted so far works as it should (just verified in an empty project). That means the problem is most likely caused by something else. Could you post the entire layout? Perhaps some elements are overlapping blocking the buttons and their `TapGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 1):

if what you're trying to tap is visible, then I'd look at whether it is getting input, one option is to turn on InputTransparent for all the items except for the image and see if that lets your image recieve you input.

see: [InputTransparent](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.InputTransparent/)

Answer (score 1):

> Can you Try this

```
NavigationPage nav = new NavigationPage(new SettingsPage());
var settingsGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
settingsGestureRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
settingsGestureRecognizer.Tapped += async(s, e) =>
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(nav);
    };
```